# How to use MAX and COUNT function in MYSQL with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, max

I am a newbie in MYSQL and had a question regarding the use of MAX and COUNT functions together in MYSQL. I have 2 tables worker and assignment and the primary key of worker is a foreign key in assignment table.

I need to show the employees name and id and the total assignment assigned to him, and only show the person with the most assignment that is the employee with the most assignment.

my code is

```
SELECT worker.Wrk_ID, worker.Wrk_LastName, MAX(a.count_id)
FROM worker,
    (SELECT COUNT(assignment.Wrk_ID) as count_ID 
        FROM worker, assignment 
        WHERE worker.Wrk_ID = assignment.Wrk_ID 
        GROUP BY worker.Wrk_ID)as a
GROUP BY worker.Wrk_ID;
```

The code is giving an error no. #1054.

Please can anyone help me.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: You are missing a where after your first from.

Comment: @DanCundy that shouldn't be necessary in general.

Comment: please post full errors, not just error code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT worker.Wrk_ID, worker.Wrk_LastName, S.Count
FROM worker 
JOIN
(SELECT Wrk_ID, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM Assignments 
GROUP BY Wrk_Id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1) S
ON worker.Wrk_ID = S.Wrk_ID
```

If you want a list of employees sorted by their total assignments:

```
SELECT w.WrkID, w.Wrk_LastName, COUNT(*) AS Assignments
FROM work w left join Assignments a
ON w.WrkID=a.WrkID
GROUP BY w.WrkID 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

To allow multiple winners:

```
SELECT s.*, w.Wrk_Lastname FROM 
(
  SELECT  wrk_id , COUNT(*) AS tot_assignments 
  FROM Assignments 
  GROUP BY wrk_id 
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 
  (
   SELECT MAX(tot) FROM 
   (
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOT FROM Assignments GROUP BY wrk_id
    ) counts
  ) 
) winners  
INNER JOIN worker w ON s.wrk_id = w.wrk_id;
```

It can be slow since it does multiple GROUP BY. Doing it in separated steps in a procedure can be better.

Comment: Can u suggest on using max and count together please

Comment: Because i need to show the employee with the most assignments, Only that employee. So i thought of using the max function.. Cant it be like this, after counting the total number of assignments assigned to each employee, than perform a max function to get the details of the employee with the most assignments..

Comment: I edited the answer to use MAX in case you have multiple winners.